# How to start a java jar with administrators privileges on windows 7

Tags: java, windows-7

I am developing a grammar with ANTLRWorks on Windows 7. The ANTLRWorks debugger doesn't start unless ANTLRWorks has Administrator privileges. ANTLRWorks is delivered as one Java .jar which starts by a doubleclick on the file.

**Question: How can I assure that the .jar file runs with Administrator Privileges ?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can run cmd under Administrator and launch ANTRLWorks using java -jar command.

Comment: That is how I do it at the moment, but I want to make a shortcut for my menu widget.

Comment: .bat file with Administrator privilegies(see Properties-Advanced), which will call @Start java -jar <your app>.

Comment: It is an improvement over the current situation where I first start a CMD with Admin Privileges and then type the jar name. - I can run the batch file As Administrator but I can't give the icon itself Administrator privileges. That is what I really want. Is that possible?

Comment: In Windows 7 you can do in [such way](http://i.piccy.info/i7/9e40501c8785d7c44d7ad3045efc512e/1-5-2793/13265383/shortcut.png).

Comment: The link does not seem to work. Are you sure the link should go to a .png file ?

Comment: That link works perfectly for me.. Try [this](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/401/shortcute.png/) one.

Comment: @ndroock1, Besides creating a shortcut, you must also have `.bat` set as an executable on your machine. (Which means double-clicking it runs it.) If your .bat is set to open with Notepad etc by deafult, you wouldn't be able to set administrator privileges for that shortcut.

Answer (score 5):

You may want to have a look at [Johannes Passing's Opensource Tool Elevate.exe](http://jpassing.com/2007/12/08/launch-elevated-processes-from-the-command-line/) There are many possibilities of using it. You can make a wrapper jar or simply use a batch file with something like:

```
Elevate.exe javaw.exe -jar path-to-your-jar-file
```

and this will launch UAC prompt, when allowed will permit the jar to have elevated privileges.

if you do not like batch files, then you can write a simple wrapper class to do so. Normally i make another jar file as a launcher for the jar which requires admin access, and in the launcher file, simply execute external process with the above command, and this way my jar has admin privileges.

Comment: btw you can package one jar inside another jar, so using above technique all you need to do is double click a jar file to do the magic

Answer (score 1):

first, download this program from here
http://code.kliu.org/misc/elevate/

then copy the "elevate.exe" file to the folder where your .jar file is.

Make, a .bat file as "elevate java -jar YourJARFile.jar".
Run the .bat file.Simple as that.